# Stream file upload to s3 via express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have an express endpoint where i currently handle uploading of files. Large files are taking lots of memory b/c i was using bodyParser which buffers the entire file in memory before calling my handler function.

I removed the bodyParser middleware from this endpoint and i'm strugging to properly use streams to basically stream the file upload -> express -> s3.

This is the docs on the s3 method and it accepts a buffer or a stream.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

route

```
router.put('/files/:filename', putHandler({ s3Client: s3Client }))
```

I tried this which streams the file to my handler method, but it doesn't seem to be streaming it to the `s3.upload` method (no surprise really)

```
function put ({ s3Client }) {
  return (req, res) => {
        ...
        let whenFileUploaded = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // const { Readable } = require('stream')
          // const inStream = new Readable({
            // read() {}
          // })

          let data = ''
          req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            req.log.debug('in chunk')
            data += chunk
            // inStream.push(chunk)
          })
          req.on('end', function () {
            req.log.debug('in end')
          })

          s3Client.upload(
            {
              Key: filepath,
              Body: data,
              SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'AES256',
              SSECustomerKey: sseKey.id.split('-').join('')
            },
            {
              partSize: 16 * 1024 * 1024, // 16mb
              queuSize: 1
            },
            (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)
          )
        })
```

My guess is that I need to create a stream and pipe `req.on('data...` to my stream and then set `Body: inStream` which you can see i attempted with the commented out stuff, but that didn't seem to work either.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is actually very simple. All I had to do was pass the `req` object.

```
function put ({ s3Client }) {
  return (req, res) => {
        ...
        let whenFileUploaded = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          s3Client.upload(
            {
              Key: filepath,
              Body: req, // <-- NOTE THIS LINE
              SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'AES256',
              SSECustomerKey: sseKey.id.split('-').join('')
            },
            {
              partSize: 16 * 1024 * 1024, // 16mb
              queuSize: 1
            },
            (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)
          )
        })
```

The way i found this out is b/c I looked at the express source code for what a `req` object is and I see that it is a `http.IncomingMessage` object - https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L31

Then i looked at the Node docs and I see that `http.IncomingMessage` implements the Readable Stream interface

> It implements the Readable Stream interface, as well as the following
>   additional events, methods, and properties.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Comment: could you detail how do you upload to this code? is it a form? post method with body? Thanks